# Excel: creating the row number with titles

Tags: excel

I would like to create an excel sheet with

```
 Cell A1 ="Step 1"
 Cell A2 ="Step 2"
 Cell A3 ="Step 3"
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: I would proceed with "Cell 4"

Answer (score 1):

You can also just put

```
Step 1
```

in A1, select the cell and drag down.
It will auto increment.

Comment: @pnuts The OP wanted to continue a series. OP wasn't aware a very simple non formula solution exists and the answer(s) work(s) so I'm wondering what the downvotes are for.

Comment: @pnuts If you put `="Step 1"` in A1 it will show as `Step 1` I don't think OP is looking to have any quotes around their text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
= "Step " & Row()
```

Comment: @pnuts I don't think you are helping anyone by downvoting all of the answers even if it is off-topic and then using the same formula in your comment.

Comment: @pnuts Why is the question off topic? There is an excel formula tag on this site after all.

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I agree with pnuts that the question is a bit off-topic and better fit for Super User because it does not ask specifically for Excel formula, but more for general help with Excel. If you check the description of the excel tag it is more clear what excel questions are on topic.

Answer (score -1):

Enter `1....N` in column `A`, and then use concatenation to build the strings you want.  Enter into cell `B1` one of the following formulas:

```
=CONCATENATE("Step ", A1)

="Step "&A1
```

Copy this formula down the `B` column as far as you need.

Comment: @pnuts Who says the OP is not trying to use actual hard data to generate the expected output?  I believe the opposite of what you said.

Comment: @pnuts I thought that he was using quotes to simply delineate what string he wanted in each cell, and hence I ignored the quotes completely.  To be clear, I answered under the assumption that he wants `Step 1` etc. in each cell and _not_ `"Step 1"`.  Let the OP comment if I be incorrect.

Comment: OK now this is getting ridiculous.  No question with three working answers should be receiving this much commentary.  You really should have closed this question as a duplicate if you feel this way.